# SQL exception thrown when the method is called otherwise working fine

Tags: mysql, jsp, netbeans

I am making a web application project using JSP in Netbeans IDE. 
I have a java Class called Login which has a static method called authenticate.When I am running this file it gives me the required output. Now I have a web page called auth.jsp which calls the method authenticate but when I try to run this web page the value returned by the method is "error" that is  sql exception is being thrown by the method. Could someone please tell why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

```
 package server;
 import java.sql.*;

 public class Login {

 public static void  main(String args[]) {

     System.out.print(authenticate("260","abc"));

    }
    public static String authenticate(String username, String password) { 

         String auth="",pass="";
         int blocked_status=0;
         String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/radio";

         try{
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","rishabh");
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();



         String sql = "select password,blocked from user where username = \"" + username + "\""; 

         ResultSet rs =  stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                 int flag=0; 

                 while(rs.next()){
                   pass = rs.getString("password");
                   blocked_status = rs.getInt("blocked"); 
                   flag++;
                  }


                if(flag>0) {

                     if(blocked_status==1)
                         auth = "blocked";
                     else if(pass.equals(password))
                         auth = "authenticated";
                     else if(pass.equalsIgnoreCase(pass))
                         auth = "wrong_case";
                     else
                         auth = "wrong_password";

                    }
                else{
                    auth = "incorrect_username";
                }


         } catch(SQLException e){
             auth = "sqlerror";
             System.out.print(" ERROR " );
         }
         return auth;   
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your sql exception?

Comment: Actually I found a way to fix it. I added this line Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"), but I don't know what this is exactly doing. SQL exception was something like this: driver not found